# Multiple split equations

Tags: macros, equations, environments, amsmath

I find myself again and again using a combination of the `gather` and `aligned` environments. So it would be nice to not have to write so much. In particular, it is often only clear after writing the formula, whether it needs splitting.
So the new environment should act like `gather`, only that when lines are separated by a special symbol/macro (`\n` for example) they should be put together into an `aligned`-environment. I tried the following

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}

\newenvironment{multeq}{%
    \let\n{\\}
    \let\\{\end{aligned}\\\begin{aligned}}
    \begin{aligned}
}{%
    \end{aligned}
    \let\\{\n}
}

\begin{document}

    \begin{gather}
        \begin{aligned}
            S(A) &= (I_{n-k, k}AI_{n-k,k})_{i,j} = (I_{n-k,k})_{i,i}A_{i,j}(I_{n-k,k})_{j,j}\\
            &= \begin{cases}A_{i,j}&\begin{aligned}&(i\leq n-k\wedge j\leq n-k)\\\vee&(i>n-k\wedge j>n-k)\end{aligned}\\-A_{i,j}&\text{otherwise}\end{cases}
        \end{aligned}\\
        \Rightarrow H = S(U(n-k)\times U(k))
    \end{gather}

    \begin{multeq}
        S(A) &= (I_{n-k, k}AI_{n-k,k})_{i,j} = (I_{n-k,k})_{i,i}A_{i,j}(I_{n-k,k})_{j,j}\n
        &= \begin{cases}A_{i,j}&\begin{aligned}&(i\leq n-k\wedge j\leq n-k)\n\vee&(i>n-k\wedge j>n-k)\end{aligned}\n-A_{i,j}&\text{otherwise}\end{cases}\\
    \Rightarrow H = S(U(n-k)\times U(k))
    \end{multeq}

\end{document}
```

where the output should be 2×
[image: example output]

but it gives the error:

```
! LaTeX Error: There's no line here to end.
l.24    \begin{multeq}
```

How does this error come about and what is a good way to create such an environment?

---

So using David’s corrections, and adding `gather`:

```
\newenvironment{multeq}{\begin{gather}%
    \def\n{\\}%
    \def\\{\end{aligned}\\\begin{aligned}}%
    \begin{aligned}%
}{%
    \end{aligned}%
    \end{gather}}
```

I got

```
! Paragraph ended before \gather was complete.
```

So I tried using `\Collect@Body` from `environ`:

```
\def\savebody#1{\def\BODY{#1}}
\usepackage{environ}
\makeatletter

\newenvironment{multeq}{
    \def\n{\\}%
    \def\\{\end{aligned}\\\begin{aligned}}%
    \Collect@Body\savebody
}{\begin{gather}%
    \begin{aligned}%
            \BODY%
    \end{aligned}%
    \end{gather}}

\makeatother
```

But now the redefinition of `\\` is ignored. What else could I do?

Comment: `\let\n{\\}`   defines `\n` to be `{` like `\bgroup`. You mean `\def` there.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: Is `\let\n\\\` ok? (and why isn't this markedup as code?)

Comment: that defines `\n` to have the current meaning of `\\ ` (the markup around backticks with backslashes and spaces in comments is a bit odd, I had to edit my previous comment a couple of times to get it to display I know what you mean though:-)

Comment: so `\let\n\\` is a legal assignment but would define ` \n ` to the wrong thing.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle (Not related to the problem) I thought I was the only one having trouble with escaping backslashes and backticks in comment markdowns. Here is an so meta post for backslashes: [Backslash escaped with backticks rendered incorrectly in comments](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/11388) as a well related post for [backticks](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12694/escaping-backticks-fails) `:-)`

Comment: @hpesoj626: thanks for the hint. let’s see, add a space: have to use `\def\n{\\}` not `\let\n{\\}` and not `\let\n\\ `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking at some macro expansions, I found the actual problem. `amsmath` defines `\let\\\math@cr` when it expands `gather`. So whatever I do to `\\` beforehand, will not matter. Thus I changed `\math@cr` et voilá, it works. At least if I collect the body with `NewEnviron`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}
\usepackage{environ}

\makeatletter
\NewEnviron{multeq}{%
    \begingroup
        \let\n\math@cr
        \begin{gather}
            \def\math@cr{\end{aligned}\n\begin{aligned}}
            \begin{aligned}
                \BODY
            \end{aligned}
        \end{gather}
    \endgroup
}
\makeatother
```

is the needed definition. It also works with `align` instead of `gather` or `split` instead of `aligned`. And for a simpler usage example:

```
\begin{document}
\begin{multeq}
    0 + 0 = 0\n
    0 * 0 = 0\\
    1 + 1 = 2\n
    1 * 1 = 1
\end{multeq}
\end{document}
```

will be printed as

[image: example output]

Answer (score 7):

You need `\def` not `\let` \nd you need to get into math mode:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}

\newenvironment{multeq}{\[%
    \def\n{\\}%
    \def\\{\end{aligned}\\\begin{aligned}}%
    \begin{aligned}%
}{%
    \end{aligned}%
    \]}

\begin{document}

    \begin{gather}
        \begin{aligned}
            S(A) &= (I_{n-k, k}AI_{n-k,k})_{i,j} = (I_{n-k,k})_{i,i}A_{i,j}(I_{n-k,k})_{j,j}\\
            &= \begin{cases}A_{i,j}&\begin{aligned}&(i\leq n-k\wedge j\leq n-k)\\\vee&(i>n-k\wedge j>n-k)\end{aligned}\\-A_{i,j}&\text{otherwise}\end{cases}
        \end{aligned}\\
        \Rightarrow H = S(U(n-k)\times U(k))
    \end{gather}

    \begin{multeq}
        S(A) &= (I_{n-k, k}AI_{n-k,k})_{i,j} = (I_{n-k,k})_{i,i}A_{i,j}(I_{n-k,k})_{j,j}\n
        &= \begin{cases}A_{i,j}&\begin{aligned}&(i\leq n-k\wedge j\leq n-k)\n\vee&(i>n-k\wedge j>n-k)\end{aligned}\n-A_{i,j}&\text{otherwise}\end{cases}\\
    \Rightarrow H = S(U(n-k)\times U(k))
    \end{multeq}

\end{document}
```

You may need some other changes, depending quite wh\t input markup you want, the above produces

[image]

Comment: Actually I wanted the new environment to be a short cut for the construction with `gather`. So to enter math mode I'd rather use `gather`. (I indeed forgot to put that into my code). Is that possible?

Comment: When I try it with `gather`, I get `! Paragraph ended before \gather was complete.`

Comment: yes just get rid of the `\[ \]` I added and replac should work by gather

Comment: Maybe I need to use `\Collect@Body` from `environ`?